# EF5; convert string like 20100326 to 2010/03/26

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, data-annotations

I have a database in which a date is saved as CHAR(8) and time is saved as CHAR(6). So for example a date in the DB looks like this: 20100326 for 2010/03/26 and time looks like: 080000 for 8 o'clock.

Of course dates and times cannot show up this way on the client and should be converted to respectively look like this: 26/04/2010 and this 8:00.

I also want to have both date and time to be converted back to the database format when they are sent to the server. I am looking for a way to have the server do this, by for example using Data Annotations on the Metadata class. But I am unable to find out how and would be grateful if someone could assist me or point me in the right direction.

I am using Entity Framework 5 and am building a web service using web api.

Tnx.

BTW: Below are the to setters/getters from the partial class containing the metadata.

```
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Properties.OrderEntryIn_Resources), Name = "DeliveryTimeFrom")]
    public string ZNGU_T { get; set; } // Time

 [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Properties.OrderEntryIn_Resources), Name = "DeliveryDateFrom")]        
    public string ZNGU_D { get; set; } // Date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we currently do for this exact issue to create a partial class and then add two properties bound to the underlying data, but which converts the data as needed. As long as the UI has access to both the partial classes you can pretty seamlessly hide the fact the DB has mad column types.

Im building on newStackExchangenInstance's answer

So, for eg.

```
public partial class JeroensCustomClass
{
    public string ZNGU_T { get; set; } // Time

    public string ZNGU_D { get; set; } // Date

    public DateTime DeliveryDateTimeFrom
    {
        get
        {
            var date = DateTime.ParseExact(ZNGU_D, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            var time = DateTime.ParseExact(ZNGU_D, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, time.Hour, time.Minute, time.Second);
        }
        set
        {
            ZNGU_D = value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            ZNGU_T = value.ToString("HHmmss");
        }
    }

}
```

You can obviously format the Date/Time on the front end, depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the way around this ... I can't say mess can I? I need to implement another part and then I will come back to this one. Thanks to both you and newStackExchangeInstance for your assistance.

Answer (score 3):

In databases, you should be using their provided `DATE`/`TIME` types.

However, what you need is (for the date):

```
//DB -> UI
DateTime.ParseExact(input, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    .ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
//UI -> DB
DateTime.ParseExact(input, "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    .ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

and for the time:

```
//DB -> UI
DateTime.ParseExact(input, "HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    .ToString("H:mm");
//UI -> DB
DateTime.ParseExact(input, "H:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    .ToString("HHmmss");
```

Comment: There is no `ParseExact` without `IFormatProvider` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx

Comment: I totally agree that DateTime should be used, sadly I am working with an old database on a which a larger system depends so I am not able to change the DataType. But do you know how I can apply this on properties of an entity by for example using data annotations?

Comment: @wudzik Should be fixed now.

Comment: @Jeroen No, sorry. (I have no experience with EF.)